# Python 2.7 : TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to make Scrabble in Python. 
The rack (where the 7 letters are) is a list where I appended 7 times tk.StringVar()
Every time the player want to drop a word, I have to get the letters off the rack. 
Here's my problem.
As I can associate the letters of the word dropped and the letters of the rack, I created a provisional list where I append each StringVar.get() from the initial rack. Then I created a code that change the dropped letters by an empty string '' as I can associate the initial rack with the provisional list. 
Here's my code

```
def defausse_rack_prov(word,rack_prov):
    word=word.get()
    for i in word:
        if i.upper() in rack_prov:
            rack_prov[rack_prov.index[i]]='' #This is the problematic line
    return rack_prov
```

I keep getting

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be `.index(i)` - parens, not brackets.

Comment: Oups, it slipped through my fingers !  :) 
Thank you !